# what is the safest jwt storage method in Angular?

Tags: angular, authentication, cookies, session-cookies

We want to store a jwt and sometimes other data as well. We usually used sessionStorage for this, but we know this is not safe.
So we want to create a new form of storage. Many people said that JWT and other information could be stored inside the cookie. Is this true or is there a safer way?

Comment: The safest way to store sensitive data on the client side is cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: Use cookies!
Any script thats being executed on your page can access both `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`, so it's significantly more risky.
More on the subject [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/jwt-authentication-best-practices/#:~:text=A%20JWT%20needs%20to%20be,storage%20(or%20session%20storage).)

For more details on how to properly configure a cookie entry for maximum security (httpOnly, sameSite and other flags) read [here](https://dev.to/gkoniaris/how-to-securely-store-jwt-tokens-51cf).